# What is self and what does it do in lua?

Tags: lua, self

I'm a new programmer in lua, and there are lots of things I still probably don't know about. I googled what self is in lua, but I still don't understand it. If anyone could give me the easiest explanation for what "self" does in lua, it would be really helpful.

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`self` is just a variable name. It is usually automatically defined by Lua if you use a special syntax.

```
function tbl:func(a) end
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
function tbl.func(self, a) end
```

That means Lua will automatically create a first parameter named `self`.

This is used together with a special function call:

```
tbl:func(a)
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
tbl.func(tbl, a)
```

That way `self` usually refers to the table. This is helpful when you do OOP in Lua and need to refer to the object from inside your method.

Similar to `this` in C++.

Comment: Great answer.  I would recommend to OP to actually code a few simple tables and functions like this and see how they work.  i.e. [***sample***](https://replit.com/@JasonGoemaat/WheatLargeProlog#main.lua)